# resizing report viewer inside a panel

Tags: c#

I have created a report with using Microsoft Report, in c#. So I put some text boxes and buttons to filter data. Then I put a panel and inside that panel I put the report viewer inside the panel, what I'm trying to do is when the form goes maximized the report also need to be maximized. I tried to dock in parent container but it didn't successful. How can I do it.

Comment: Is this in windows form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose, you are using Windows Forms. Two things:

1. The Panel's property make `Dock` to `Fill`
   and
2. The Report tool's property make `Dock` to `Fill`.

The Issue must be, you might have made the Report background control's `Dock` to `Fill`, but not the Panel. Hence the Panel remains the same size, even when the Form is in the maximized state.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I separated the filtering part and the report viewer. then I changed the Dock Property to "Fill". Thanks D.